# Can't start gpg-agent on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnupg

I have upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.

When i run **gpg-agent** its says:

```
gpg-agent: relocation error: gpg-agent: symbol gcry_get_config version GCRYPT_1.6 not defined in file libgcrypt.so.20 with link time reference
```

What is the problem?

I want to create a gpg key for my github account but the **gpg --gen-key** gives

```
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
Key generation failed: No agent running
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.
I updated the libgcrypt to 1.8 (previous was on 1.7) and now gpg-agent works.

Comment: How did you update libgcrypt? Did you install libgcrypt through apt?

Comment: Manually, download and build the source.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well.  Run:

```
sudo apt-get install gpg-agent
```

You should then be able to create your gpg key.

Comment: This is likely not the issue: this command installs gpg-agent. The error message the OP has indicates gpg-agent is already installed on his system.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in the distant past, I had built and installed to /usr/local(lib and bin) which shadowed the new release. Easily solved by checking /usr/local for the shadow executables and libraries and then run ldconfig and hash -r.